# MappingException: No mapping file found named for ManytoMany join table after upgrade

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

After upgrading Symfony from 2.6 to 3.2 I get this error in my logs for one of my users, however I'm not sure how to reproduce it:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "No mapping file found named 'VetControlClinic.orm.yml' for class 'AgriHealth\AhpBundle\Entity\VetControlClinic
```

This is the join table of a bidirectional many-to-many relation. The relevant schema details are:

```
AgriHealth\AhpBundle\Entity\Vet:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: AgriHealth\AhpBundle\Entity\VetRepository
    manyToOne:
        clinic:
            targetEntity: Clinic
            inversedBy: VetsOfClinic
            joinColumn:
                name: clinic_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    oneToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: User
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    manyToMany:
        clinics:
            targetEntity: Clinic
            inversedBy: Vets
            joinTable:
                name: vet_control_clinic
                joinColumns:
                    vet_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    clinic_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id

AgriHealth\AhpBundle\Entity\Clinic:
    type: entity
    table: clinic
    repositoryClass: AgriHealth\AhpBundle\Entity\ClinicRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    manyToMany:
        Vets:
            targetEntity: Vet
            mappedBy: clinics
```

I'm not sure what to add in VetControlClinic.yml, according to Doctrine documentation, nothing should be required?

Comment: Does your vet_control_clinic table have any additional columns?  If so then you need a VetControlClinic entity.  But I assume this was all working under 2.6 so it seems strange unless the table was somehow modified.

Comment: no additional columns, just 2 setters and getters in the entity. It does have a repository class, which is strange.

Comment: ManyToMany has no intermediate entity at all.  It can't.  If you do have a VetControlClinic entity then instead of a ManyToMany relation between Vet and Clinic, you actually have OneToMany relations between Vet and VetControlClinic and between Clinic and VetControlClinic.  Are you sure nothing was changed between 2.6 and 3.2?  I just can't see how this would have worked in 2.6.  Doctrine has changed between D2.4 and D2.5 but not that much.